# MYsql Select comparing two tables dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I did this search to match date resouts from two different table and it's working but the problem is that it's too slow.
 Does anyone has an idea how to optimize that ?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS
(SELECT codigo, MAX(data) as datucm 
FROM tbentradaitem WHERE YEAR(data)>=Year(NOW())-2 GROUP BY codigo
);
SELECT tbpedidoitem.codigo, SUM( tbpedidoitem.qtd )
FROM  `tbpedidoitem`, table2 
WHERE
(tbpedidoitem.codigo = table2.codigo AND tbpedidoitem.data >= table2.datucm )
GROUP BY tbpedidoitem.codigo;
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: can you provide some table definition and specify if you have any indexes or any partitioning is involved ?

Answer (score 0):

Add index to codigo and datucm column of table table2

ALTER TABLE table2 ADD INDEX INDEX_1 (codigo,datucm);

Create temporary table as myisam

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT tbpedidoitem.codigo, SUM( tbpedidoitem.qtd )
FROM  `tbpedidoitem`
WHERE
tbpedidoitem.codigo = MAX(tbpedidoitem.data)
GROUP BY tbpedidoitem.codigo
```

Comment: An answer with nothing but code might be correct, but is not as useful as an answer with both code and an explanation. Other users may want to know *why* this is correct and *how* to arrive at this solution.